# Colleague cannot put down her phone... even while teaching!

Tags: performance, mistakes

A colleague cannot put down her phone, not for a moment. She's a lecturer in English. Today I came into one of her classes, and she was holding her phone in front of her face with one hand while reading from a textbook held in the other. Amazing to behold. She was giving a dictation test and chatting and giggling at the same time! This is forbidden at my university. I could not help but notice that she is doing a rather poor job. She is not focused on her work at all. She does this every time I see her, which is about three times a week.

We are very friendly with each other and I do not want to make her angry. At the same time, I am astounded that she has started to do this, and now I feel that I should say something. I am not going to go tell on her, so I either let it go or I figure out a way to tell her to knock it off.

**How should I tell her to stop?**  Just to be clear, her habit clearly gets in the way of her work, and that means the students are not getting what they deserve.

Comment: Did she pick up that behaviour recently? For how long have you known her?

Comment: @iLuvLogix  I have known her for three years. She started this behavior about three weeks ago. I don't know why she is doing this.

Comment: chances are good that she has met someone she's romantically interested in, which would explain the sudden change in behaviour and inability to put down the phone.

Comment: @Stun Brick  That did cross my mind.  About two weeks ago she completely missed a class without telling anyone beforehand.  I just happened to be there to find a substitute, and so nothing untoward happened.

Comment: @Patriot there might also be an issue (medical, family, ...) for which she needs to be available/keeping up with updates that you don't know of. Unlikely with her suddenly giggling and chatting, but worth keeping in mind.

Comment: Since this appears to be in an academic setting, this may also be appropriate over at [academia.se]

Comment: @DavidK  That would be like having to attend a meeting, which is the very last thing that I need.  (I am laughing.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could consider your relation with that person (lets call her 'Mary') as a friendship. As a friend you should address this issue and speak to her. Maybe something along those lines:

*"Mary - I recently started noticing that you seem a little distracted by using your smartphone during lectures and other work related activities. I'm a bit worried that this behaviour during work can have a negative impact on how colleagues and your students perceive your work ethic"*

If she continues with her bahaviour you could step up a bit and mention that this could get her reported or even fired..

Comment: I think you hit the nail on the head: " ...a negative impact on how colleagues and your students perceive your work ethics."  That is it.  The students will see the negative thing and imitate it--we can't have that.

Comment: So, I have to say something.  It is my duty as a teacher.  I will mention its negative impact on the students.

Comment: Not enough for an edit but it's 'work ethic'.

Comment: @jcm Thanks for the hint ;)  I've edited my answer accordingly..

Answer (score 6):

If you don't have managerial authority over her then you cannot *tell* her to stop.

You might consider suggesting or advising though.

If all else fails, will you report her behavior to management / the Dean / HR ?

I know if I did that in class then the students would report me... But I don't take my phone to class...

Comment: Right. One of the students might report her. That's probably the answer--ask her to stop before a student says something.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if you're in a PhD program with this person or if they're an adjunct or full-time lecturer. But in my experience with colleagues, i.e. other PhD students who are teaching university courses, I would advise the following:

1. Talk to your colleague. Ask what's up with the phone/textbook thing: I assume it's unrelated to the course? Double-check it's not part of your friend's new digital humanities curriculum.
2. Tell your colleague why you're concerned. Is it because the university students won't be getting a quality education? You're worried about a dean coming in and her being reprimanded and/or fired. I imagine that the student course evaluations won't look great if they're on the phone when they should be teaching.